# Silence gem list console output

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems

I'm writing a bash script to run a ruby command and it requires a few gems. I'm checking if the gem is installed and installing it like so:

```
if ! gem list rest-client -iq
then
    echo "Missing rest-client gem, installing now..."
    gem install rest-client
fi
```

This works great, except for the fact that is outputs `true` or `false`. Looking at the help pages, I think adding the `q` option is suposed to silence this output, however I may be wrong.

How do I go about suppressing the `true` or `false` output and just act on it?

Comment: As always, you can hide the stdout by redirecting it to `/dev/null` --> `gem list rest-client -iq >/dev/null && echo "yes" || echo "no"`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, if you want to add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, just redirect the `stdout` to `/dev/null` so that it does not show:

```
if ! gem list rest-client -iq >/dev/null
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^
then
    echo "Missing rest-client gem, installing now..."
    gem install rest-client
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--silent` flag.

```
gem list -i rest-client --silent
```